# Add two attribute values and display the result as a column in admin grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

I have an admin grid with two attributes of customer (`attr1` and `attr2`). I can display them in the grid as two separate columns with `addAttributeToSelect` method.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attr1', 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attr2', 'left');
    ...
```

I need to add a **third** column displaying the sum of the values of those attributes. I can display this column too, with `addExpressionFieldToSelect`.

```
    ...
        ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('sum', 'SUM({{attr1}})+SUM({{attr2}})', array(
            'attr1', 'attr2'
        );

    $collection->getSelect()->group('e.email');
}
```

The problem is if I filter the `sum` column, Magento gives me an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_int` AS `at_attr1` ON (`at_attr1`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_attr1`.`attribute_id` = '866')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_int` AS `at_attr2` ON (`at_attr2`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_attr2`.`attribute_id` = '864')
 WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') AND (SUM(at_attr1.value)+SUM(at_attr2.value) >= '0.000000') GROUP BY `e`.`email`
```

I tried to define a custom filter callback:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
        'width' => '300px',
        'index' => 'email'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('attr1', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Attr 1'),
        'index' => 'attr1',
        'type' => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
    ));
    $this->addColumn('attr2', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Attr 2'),
        'index' => 'attr2',
        'type' => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
    ));
    $this->addColumn('sum', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('core')->__('SUM'),
        'index' => 'sum',
        'type' => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
        'filter_index' => 'sum',
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterSum'),
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _filterSum($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (isset($value['from'])) {
        $collection->getSelect()->having('sum > '.$value['from']);
    }
    if (isset($value['to'])) {
        $collection->getSelect()->having('sum < '.$value['to']);
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return $this;
}
```

But this time I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum' in 'having clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
 WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') GROUP BY `e`.`email` HAVING (sum > 0)
```

So, my question is how can I display the sum of two attributes in an admin grid?

Comment: In my case `addExpressionFieldToSelect` did the job (as I use non EAV attributes but mere fields of a custom table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I got the `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum' in 'having clause'` is Magento removes everything after `SELECT` statement in order to replace them with `COUNT(*)`. You can see it in `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php`:

```
/**
 * Get SQL for get record count
 *
 * @return Varien_Db_Select
 */
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $this->_renderFilters();

    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS); // <--

    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');

    return $countSelect;
}
```

So the result query, as mentioned in the error message was this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
 WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') GROUP BY `e`.`email` HAVING (sum > 0)
```

Hence the error.

But it doesn't remove attributes added using `addAttributeToFilter` method. So I "kind of" solved my problem by filtering `attr1` and `attr2` using a filter I know is always true:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attr1', 'left')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attr2', 'left');
        ->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('sum', 'SUM({{attr1}})+SUM({{attr2}})', array(
            'attr1', 'attr2'
        )
        // I added these dummy filters:
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attr1', array(
            array('gt' => -1000000000000),
            array('null' => true)
        ))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attr2', array(
            array('gt' => -1000000000000),
            array('null' => true)
        );

    $collection->getSelect()->group('e.email');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    return $this;
}
```

I would be very happy if anyone could come up with a better solution.

Comment: Since there were no better answers, I mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this wonderful question.

You can use the grid renderer feature to do this job. So specify your custom renderer in your `sum` grid column like below:

```
$this->addColumn('sum', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('SUM'),
    'index' => 'sum',
    'type' => 'text',
    'renderer' => 'Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid_Renderer_Sum',
));
```

Now you need to define this render class inside your module `Namespace_Module`.

File: `app/code/[local]/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid/Renderer/Sum.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid_Renderer_Sum extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Render sum total of attr1 and attr2.
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $sum   = null;
        $attr1 = $row->getData('attr1');
        $attr2 = $row->getData('attr2');
        if (isset($attr1) && isset($attr2)) {
            $sum = $attr1 + $attr2;
        }

        return Mage::helper('core')->currency($sum, true, false);;

    }
}
```

I hope the answer will give you some insights on how to approach this situation. Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks. I tested your suggestion. The same error occurs: `General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function...`

Comment: You don't need to add `addExpressionFieldToSelect()` in your collection. please remove that if you are still using it.

Comment: So what should I set for `index` key? Should I still use `sum`?

Comment: keep it as `sum`

Comment: It doesn't work: `Invalid attribute sum`. Because if I remove `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` part there will be no `sum` field in the query.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easiest way to solve your problem.

First you need to get concat two attributes as one attribute by using CONCAT function

In Prepare Collection,

```
$collection->join(array('soas' => 'sales/order_address'), 'soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', 
                    array('full_billing_address'=>'CONCAT( soas.street, ",", soas.city, ",", soas.region)'
                  ), null,'left');
```

In Prepare Columns function,

```
$this->addColumn('full_billing_address', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill Address'),
            'index' => 'full_billing_address',
            'filter_index' => 'CONCAT( soas.street, ",", soas.city, ",", soas.region)',
        ));
```

(or)

```
$this->addColumn('full_billing_address', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill Address'),
            'index' => 'full_billing_address',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_billAddressFilter'),
        ));
```

And put the following function in grid file if You used '**'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_billAddressFilter'),**'

```
protected function _billAddressFilter($collection, $column) {
        $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        if (!$value) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("CONCAT(soas.street, ',', soas.city, ',', soas.region) LIKE '%".$value."%'");

        return $this;
    }
```

Try this..!